# export latex symbol in src block org mode to latex and html

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm writing some pseudo code having some symbols like λ (\lambda). Enabling `org-toggle-pretty-entities` converts \lambda to λ in buffer, however when I export to HTML or latex, they are not converted. How can I use these symbols in src block.

I'm okay with using example, verse block or any other way of preserving newlines.

Comment: what's the language within your src_block?

Comment: @dangom: like I said, I'm writing pseudo code, which looks like lisp. These are small snippets, I'm not that interested in having code highlight. I'm happy with pre formatting for newlines and symbols.

Comment: Doesn't matter. What is the name of the language that you give to your source block?! That is what defines the functionality you get. You can't just write any Pseudocode that comes to mind and expect Org mode to know how to parse it.

Comment: @dangom I gave 'Scheme'.

Comment: What happens if you just insert the Unicode symbol for lambda directly on the buffer?

Comment: Yes! that works! But writing \lambda or \beta is much more convenient than searching for Unicode symbols and then pasting them. Is there any easier way of inserting Unicode symbols.

Comment: Check out abbrev mode and yassnippet

Comment: This is a good work around, do you mind adding this as an answer. This might be helpful for others. Also another way to insert unicode is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863576/emacs-automatically-replace-latex-to-unicode-symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Org SRC_BLOCK blocks, LaTeX inputs are not interpreted nor converted to symbols on export. You can tweak the export, though, to achieve what you want:

The following filter replaces `\lambda` by their equivalent Unicode symbol:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
      (defun my-lambda-to-unicode (output backend info)
        "Convert lambda to Unicode on export to html."
        (when (and (eq backend 'html)
                   (string-match "\\\\lambda" output))
          (replace-match "&#955;" nil nil output)))

      (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
                   'my-lambda-to-unicode)
#+END_SRC
```

A simpler workaround, though, consists in entering the equivalent Unicode symbol directly into the buffer. To make the process easier you can use [`abbrev-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode), and have lambda be converted to the Unicode [small greek lambda](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bb/index.htm) automatically. Here's a [tutorial](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_n_unicode.html) on how to deal with Unicode in Emacs.

An alternative is to use [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) and have snippets to insert symbols. The abbrev seems more efficient, though.

Comment: Since this is a work around, I'll wait a day or two to accept this answer. I've an impression that there is nothing which cannot be changed in Emacs. I'm sure there must be some way to tweak export to interpret LaTeX symbols.

Comment: Just edited to add what you want.

Comment: You were right, directly adding Unicode is much simpler for someone who don't deal with Unicode everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to directly begin a `lstlisting` environment instead of using `#+begin_src`. Of course this might not work with HTML exports though.

You would also need to add `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, mathescape}` in your LaTeX headers.